# Does Java have something similar to c++'s combinable?

Tags: java, c++, multithreading

I am using `.parallelStream().forEach()` to do a bunch of writes to a DB, but would also like to keep a count of the rows I've written.

Right now, I have an `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger` to keep track of the count, but I would like to use something similar to c++'s `combinable<>`.

In [this article](https://katyscode.wordpress.com/2013/08/17/c11-multi-core-programming-ppl-parallel-aggregation-explained/), there is an example of the use of `combinable<>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <ppl.h>

using namespace Concurrency;

const int max_sum_item = 1000000000;

int main()
{
    combinable<uint64_t> part_sums([] { return 0; });

    parallel_for(0, max_sum_item,
        [&part_sums] (int i)
        {
            part_sums.local() += i;
        }
    );

    uint64_t result = part_sums.combine(std::plus<uint64_t>());

    if (result != uint64_t(499999999500000000))
        throw;
}
```

Is there an equivalent `combinable<>` class in Java?

Java code snippet:

```
AtomicInteger totalRows = new AtomicInteger(0);
...
myList.parallelStream().forEach(
    ... // write to db
    totalRows.addAndGet(rowsWritten);
    ...
);

print(totalRows.get());
```

Looking for something like:

```
Combinable<int> totalRows = new Combinable<>(0);
...
myList.parallelStream().forEach(
    ... // write to db
    totalRows = rowsWritten;
    ...
);

print(totalRows.combine());
```

EDIT: as per @zero323, the right tool in Spark would be an [`Accumulator`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/Accumulator.html). I'm more interested in a multi-threaded case, but don't have a non-Spark example on hand atm.

EDIT2: Updated example (and removing Spark references)

Comment: This might be nitpicking but it's not "c++'s combinable" as it's not part of any c++ standard. The `concurrency` namespace is part of Microsoft's abstraction over their concurrency runtime and as such is not portable either.

Answer (score 2):

A right tool in Spark would be an [`Accumulator`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/Accumulator.html):

```
Accumulator<Integer> accum = sc.accumulator(0);

myRDD.parallelStream().forEach(
    accum.add(1);
);

accum.value();
```

Accumulators are write-only from a worker perspective and only can be read only by a driver. By default it supports only `Long`, `Double` and `Float` but you can implement a custom `AccumulatorParam` to support other types.

Comment: Sounds good. I tried to word the question for any multi-threaded scenario, but sadly I didn't have a non-Spark one.

Comment: Spark is actually quite specific scenario where accumulator is actually the only clean option. If you have Scala-like collection API relatively good approach is to generate side effects inside parallel map, return indicator and reduce.